# How to list the most expensive and the cheapest item in each category in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I need to get a list of categories and then get the most expensive item and then the cheapest item out of each category. Then I need to sort these categories by the sum of min and max price in ASC order. I've tried this:

```
SELECT k.name AS Category, p.name AS MostExpensive, p.name AS Cheapest, Max(price),Min(price)
FROM category k, item p
WHERE  p.category_id=k.category_id 
GROUP BY k.name,p.name
ORDER BY Min(price)+Max(price) ASC;
```

Now this partially works. It does give me a list of categories ordered, it gives me price of the cheapest and most expensive item . But the problem is that it doesn't do it in one row. For example, I get this in the first 2 rows:

Anyways, I need this table to look different, I need one row in which there will be category CD, then listed CD-RW as the most expensive item in a column right next to CD, and then right next to that another column with CD-R as the cheapest item. Basically, this same thing but only in 1 row .

I'd really appreaciate if somebody could help me out with this

Comment: Your chances of getting a good answer is much better if you provide an example of the data you are querying and what you want to output to look like. Screens shots are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `keep` clause as following:

```
SELECT k.name as cat_name,
       max(p.name) keep (dense_rank last order by price) as expensive_item,
       max(price) as max_price,
       max(p.name) keep (dense_rank first order by price) as cheapest_item, 
       min(price) as min_price
FROM category k join item p
On (p.category_id=k.category_id)
GROUP BY k.name
ORDER BY Min(price)+Max(price);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: could you just please explain to me why are we using first and last after dense_rank , I don't understand that

Comment: First and last decides giving the numbers to the row using dense rank. So for max we want last row and min, we want first row.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the sunquery for min and max price group by category with the table item one for max price and one for min price

```
select  p1.name AS MostExpensive, p2.name, t1.max_price, t1.min_price
FROM  (
  SELECT k.name AS Category,  Max(price) max_price, Min(price) min_price
  FROM category k
  INNER JOIN item p ON  p.category_id=k.category_id 
  GROUP BY k.name
 ) t1 
 INNER JOIN Item  p1 ON p1.price = t1.max_price
 INNER JOIN Item  p2 ON p2.price = t1.min_price
```

And you should not use (old) implicit join syntax based on `WHERE`; you should use explicit join syntax based on `ON` clause.